# add additional line before the beginning of the document

Tags: moderncv

Firstly, I would like to add additional line before the beginning of the document, I added a red cross where I would like to do this.

[image]

And secondly,I would like to change the police of the right side of my document where you found some informations like my telephone number, etc...

And finally, how can I add a photo of me? for exemple in the left side by reducing the size of "mehmet demir" & "etudiant en ..." elements...

You can find my code here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
% Largeur de la colonne pour les dates
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm}

%\usepackage{palatino}
\firstname{Mehmet}
\familyname{Demir}
\title{Étudiant en réseaux et télécommunications}              
\address{50, rue de la Paix}{77270 Villeparisis}    
\email{demir.mehmet90@gmail.com}                      
%\homepage{www.madrzejewski.com}
\mobile{06 52 42 28 65} 
\extrainfo{23 ans -- Permis B / Véhiculé}
```

If anyone can help me, please :)

Comment: @Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What kind of line do you mean? Just empty white space?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I would like to add text like "student engineering school" etc...

Comment: Unless you want people to pay you a visit next time they're in your neck of the woods, you probably should remove personal details from your code before posting on this site...

Comment: @Jubobs Informations used are not true, except my firstname & lastname...

Comment: What do you not like about the police?